# How to create an archive page (with links) for a date range?

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, archives

Is there a plugin which can create an Archive page for a limited date range?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The WordPress [wp_get_archives()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_archives) function makes this really easy.

At the bare minimum, you can specify the type and the limit and it will return a collection of posts within that range.